# Why don't more people randomise their global namespace object if the goal is to avoid polluting the global scope?

Tags: javascript

What's the real danger here?  It doesn't seem to add up - am I missing something?  After reading through RequireJS docs and Addy Osmani's design patterns (module section) - it seems most people have no problem returning a static, predefined object name for creating their app/plugin/module's namespace..

I can see where we wouldn't want to wait for all other scripts to load to define our own, but that aside... as long as I put all of my code for an app into as few globally name spaced objects as possible... does it matter?

Comment: What does "randomise the global namespace object" mean?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear - I'm not sure what you're missing?  It's the difference between doing something like (function(x){//dostuff})(var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};)  aaaand (function(x){//dostuff})(randomiseNameSpace()); the latter of which returns something random.  If your question is rhetorical please explain!

Comment: Your explanation is not so clear I think, tell me if I'm right: you're asking why namespaces don't use a random name each time they are loaded ?

Comment: If you use a random global name, then how does the code that needs to access that global resource know what name to access it by?  It seems you'd have to store the name you were using somewhere globally in a known global name and that defeats the entire purpose.  If you're doing something different than this, then please show the code so we aren't confused as to what you're doing and what you're asking about.  Also, the first choice is to put persistent state into a closure anyway so it persists, is accessible as desired, but is not actually global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a library, you need to provide your users (sometimes yourself) some way to use it. So let's try this as a random experiment:

I have created a cool library which allows you to add 3D real-time chat to your website. The namespace of this library is random. No, I won't tell you what it is, it is random. You may use it any way you like since I've licensed it under a liberal Creative Commons license.

Now here's a challenge for you. Use my library.

What? You want me to provide documentation? OK, sure:

> To start the 3D chat call the init() function like this: ????.init(). Note: Replace ???? with the proper namespace for the library. No, I'm not going to tell you what it is because I don't know it: it's random. Yes, it will change every time someone loads a page.

Without knowing what the namespace is you can't really use the library.

I can make it a bit easier and have a slightly more structured namespace. Let's give it a namespace of `Chat3D_????` where ???? will always be replace with a 4 digit random number (you know, to avoid polluting the global scope).

In order to use this version of the library you'd have to do something like this:

```
for (var i = 1111; i < 9999: i++) {
    if (window['Chat3D_' + i]) {
        window['Chat3D_' + i].init();
        break;
    }
}
```

Now that's just silly.

---

If your code is not a library, meaning that no other users will call it (not even yourself), then javascript already provides a better mechanism than randomized variable names to avoid polluting the global scope: IIFE:

```
(function(){

    // all your code go here

})();
```

---

So, either some other code need to use your code. In which case you should provide a global reference (and preferably only ONE global reference - ie. a namespace). Or no other code need to use your code. In which case you can hide everything inside a closure.

There is no use case where a random namespace makes sense.

---

### Additional answer:

Node.js shows us another way to completely avoid polluting the global scope yet allowing you to use a library: Node modules allow you, the user, to chose what the name of namespace will be:

```
var my_custom_namespace_for_3D_chat = require('3Dchat');
```

Note that from a usability point of view implementing the 3Dchat module shouldn't require the author to create random variable names. I concede however that one may implement such module feature with randomized global variables. Though that's not an implementation I'd choose. Still, from the average programmers perspective neither the library author nor the library user should need to randomize the module's name/namespace. That's the job of the module system (a bit like C++ variable name mangling in old implementations that compile C++ to C).

However, this doesn't at all solve the issue of name collisions. Yes, you avoid global variable name collisions completely with this but you still have module name collisions. Another person can't create another library called `'3Dchat'` and expect to use the same `require` statement.

Comment: Someone who doesn't pretend to not understand and explains it like a man :)